# Left callout image not showing up in MKMapView annotation view

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but it just wont work.

My `mapView: viewForAnnotation:` looks like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *aView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"ImageMapView"];
    if (!aView)
    {
        aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ImageMapView"];
        aView.canShowCallout = YES;
        aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    }
    [(UIImageView *)aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:nil];
    aView.annotation = annotation;
    return aView;
}
```

so every new annotation starts with a blank image view in the left callout.

Now when the callout is touched the next code is executed:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    //loading an image
    [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:image];
}
```

And with the help of logging I know that image's url and data are ok, and *image* itself is not nil, but nothing shows up in the left callout.

Can anyone suggest me how can I track down the source of this problem?

### EDIT

I've added some logs, so I can see what's going on:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    UIImage *image = [self.delegate imagesMapViewController:self thumbnailForAnnotation:view.annotation];
    NSLog(@"Image was: %@", [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView image]);
    NSLog(@"Image received: %@", image);
    [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:image];
    NSLog(@"Image became: %@", [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView image]);
}
```

and I end up with the next output:

```
Image was: (null)
Image received: <UIImage: 0x7933470>
Image became: <UIImage: 0x7933470>
```

so the image is being set, but is not showing up, I have no idea why. Also the first logging information appears only after the second annotation view was taped, so it's quite unusual that the first annotation view is not calling `mapView: didDeselectAnnotationView:`

Also when I put

```
[(UIImageView *)aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:[self.delegate imagesMapViewController:self thumbnailForAnnotation:aView.annotation]];
```

instead of

```
[(UIImageView *)aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:nil];
```

in `mapView: viewForAnnotation:` all left callout accessories have images like they should to, but *off source* I want to download images on demand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you use

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

when you should use

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

cheers )

Comment: Damn it. I seams that autocompletion isn't always a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your didSelectAnnotationView method will work if you're loading the image from a variable. If so, you'll need to refer to the original annotation:

```
-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    MyAnnotation *pin = (MyAnnotation *) [view annotation];
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pin.flag]];

}
```

Hope this enhances the original answer...  :)

Answer (score 1):

In mine, I have a push segue from the MapViewController to the UIImageView with Identifier set for the Push segue.

I have this protocol in MapViewController  in .h:

```
    @protocol MapViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)mapViewController:(MapViewController *)sender imageForAnnotation:(MKAnnotationView *)annotation;
    -(void)mapViewController:(MapViewController *)sender annotationSegue:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
    @end
```

Then I define the delegate in the MapViewController.h @interface:

```
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id <MapViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

You may not need the required protocol methods above.  I'm not sure.

I'm seeing that the difference between your viewforAnnotation and mine is I have two lines flipped:

```
    aView.annotation = annotation;
    [(UIImageView *)aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:nil];
```

After this method, you see the map and select the pin.  Then it goes to didSelectAnnotioatnView as I show above with the delegate.

I also have a PhotoListTableViewController that has this method:

```
    -(void)mapViewController:(MapViewController *)sender imageForAnnotation:(MKAnnoatioatnView *)annotation
    {
        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create ("flickrUrls", NULL);
        dispatch_asynch(downloadQueue, ^{
            FlickrPhotoAnnotation *fpa = (FlickrPhotoAnnotation *) annotation.annotation;
            NSURL *url = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:fpa.phot format:FlickrPhotoFormatSquare];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                [(UIImageView *)annotation.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:image];
            });
        });
        dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
    }
```

So I believe this shows the root cause (above).  So you can see, the above sets the image.  The method you had initializes it to nil to start out.  Also, my PhotoListTableViewController that implements the above method in the .m part of the @interface you see

```
    @interface PhotoListTableViewController()<MapViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: Though your's answer hasn't helped me, it probably can help to find some solution, so please clean up all the off topic stuff, so other people can see a solution only concerning this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    if([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MyLocation class]]) {

        __weak MKAnnotationView *weakView = view;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:((MyLocation*)weakView.annotation).thumbnailUrl];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

                UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                weakView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This means that it just starts to download it when you what it, and when its done, it animates the view to make room for the image.